# Google Assistant verify user input in Dialogflow webhook

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Some info first: My Google Assistant chatbot currently has 2 functions (intents), that is to register a user (input: user's name and surname, date of birth and an ID) and to make a payment to another user (input: recipient's name and ID and the amount to be paid). I have it all set up, with an index.js webhook linking to firebase.

Below is the code I currently use for the 2 intents:

```
app.intent('onboard user', (conv, {name, surname, birthdate, ID}) => {
  var user = db.collection("Users").doc(ID);

  var setUser = user.set({
    "FirstName": name,
    "Surname": surname,
    "DateofBirth": new Date(birthdate),
    "ID": ID,
    "AccountCreated": new Date(),
  });
    conv.close('Is this correct? Your full name is ' + name + ' ' + surname + '. You were born on ' + birthdate + ' and your ID is ' + ID);
});

app.intent('payment', (conv, {recipient, amount, ID}) => {
  var transactionRef = db.collection("Transactions").doc(ID);

  var setTransaction = transactionRef.set({
  "Recipient": recipient,
  "Amount": amount,
  "ID": ID,
  "Date": new Date(),
});
  conv.close('Is this correct? You wish to pay ' + recipient + ' with ID ' + ID + ' ' + amount.amount + ' ' + amount.currency);
});
```

I have some very simple requirements that I want to implement, that is, to verify that the specified IDs are more than 6 digits, and preferably that the Date of Birth is within a reasonable range (Probably between 1910 and 2010).

The problem is I have not been able to find a clear guide on how to do this. I originally followed Google's tutorials on the Google Assistant & Dialogflow, as well as some other guides online. But I feel like that didn't give me an understanding of anything above the bare basics of developing for the Assistant.

I looked at follow-up intents, but I specifically want to call them if my requirements are not met. In simple terms:

```
if(ID.length < 6){
    \\assistant gives informative response asking and prompts for ID again
}
```

So if I could ask for help with that, as well as maybe any good guides/tutorials that serves as a good resource for broadening the understanding of developing for the assistant, that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the recently released Dialogflow tutorial https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook#whats_next

Comment: Please, read the [ANSWERING TECHNICAL QUESTIONS HELPFULLY](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) blog.

Answer (score 0):

First: You shouldn't use `conv.close(your answer)`since this ends the conversation. If you use that the Assistant will simply answer and after that you would hear the earcon for a closed action.

Instead use `conv.ask("your question")` to give the answer to the user's question and then ask for more input. You can use multiple `conv.ask()` statements for each intent. So the first could be used to actually provide information to the user.

For the first sample you did use, I would transform it like this:

```
conv.ask('Thanks. I understood, that your full name is ' + name + ' ' + surname + '. You were born on ' + birthdate + ' and your ID is ' + ID);
conv.ask('Is this correct?')
```

It's important first to give the user some information about what the user input (with voice this is tremendously important since they have no other feedback). And then to ask a question so that the user knows that she can (in fact should) speak again.

Second: About verifying the input: That's normal Javascript. So as you have shown above, you could again do something like this:

```
if (ID.length < 6){
    conv.ask(`I understood your ID to be ${ID}. But it should be at least six digits long. Can you repeat the ID please?`);
} else {
    // the code from above
}
```

This sample uses JS template strings. I prefer them over String concatenation. But you have to use backticks for them to work! But it's up to you which style to choose.

Finally: Consider using [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml). Especially if the ID uses characters using the  element would be helpful, because you could make it spell each character separately instead of trying to make a word out of it (which in the case of IDs would sound weird). But of course, the first two things are the important parts. You can polish the response afterwards :-)